# swiftui double with 7 decimals without rounding

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a number with 7 decimals in SwuifUI:

```swift
@State var newLatitude : Double = 47.6364658

Text("\(newLatitude)") //this displays 47.636466
```

But this will round automatically to 47.636466 that only has 6 decimals

How can I avoid this?
Use another data type? I still want to use the Double because I have a shared Kotlin repo.

Also I need the exact 7 decimals without rounding because this is a geolocation point.

The way that i get the data from kotlin shared repo:

```
func getDoubleFromKotlin() {
    Task{
        do{
            try await repo.getData().watch(block:{myValue in                           
                self.newLatitude = myValue.latitude as Double// what data type should be?                             
            })
        }
    }
}
```

What type new latitude should have to not be automatically rounded and lose the real 7 decimal value?

Comment: Show, in your question, how you use the Double that results in it being rounded.

Comment: I added, a simple text will round automatically

Comment: You need to use `Decimal`. `Float` and `Double` are using the IEEE 754 standard for single/double precision floating point. They simply don't have a notion of "7 digits". They operate in base 2, so they can be accurate to a certain number of bits. The kind of imprecision you get from `0.1 + 0.2` not equalling exactly `0.3` is exactly the same as how you can't express `1/3` in decimal. So you see, your question is equivalent to "How do I express 1/3 in decimal?". The answer is, you simply can't. You can write any number of 3s in `0.33333...`, but anything short of infinite will be imprecise.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use the Decimal?

Comment: `Text("\(newLatitude)")` uses a default rounding of numbers. If you want something more specific, use a `NumberFormatter` or whatever the equivalent is in SwiftUI.

Comment: Example? do you have any advice?

Comment: @dhaval123 Something like: `Text(String(format:"%.7f", newLatitude))`. That will round the value to 7 decimal places.

Comment: And what will be the data type? I need a data type to get from kotlin

Comment: I ve eddited the post, how I should get the double from the kotlin, without changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Decimal128, which is a Realm supported type in both [Swift](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#supported-property-types) as well as [Kotlin](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/schemas/supported-types/).

It's quite powerful - you can even store and work with currency; it's similar to NSDecimalNumber. Here's some Swift examples:

```
var decNum = Decimal128(value: 47.6364658) //decimal to Decimal128

var stringNum = Decimal128(string: "47.6364658") //string to Decimal128

var intNum = Decimal128(integerLiteral: 44) //int to Decimal128
```

or even from an NSNumber

```
let num = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 47.6364658)
var x = Decimal128(number: num)
```

You can also easily get the magnitude, which is handy when calculating distances

```
let m = num.magnitude
```

Get it as a string for outputting to UI

```
let s = dec128Num.stringValue
print(s)

47.6364658
```

If you need to format the number in Swift, please use [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter) which provides a lot of flexibility for significant digits etc. I don't know what the Kotlin equivalent is.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the original question, all you need to do is to properly format your value. In SwiftUI you can do it directly in the `TextField`

```
Text(newLatitude.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(2...))))
```

The open ended range, `2...`, will mean it will use at least 2 decimal digits and up to as many as the value contains.

This works fine with `Double` but you can also use `Decimal`